# Onmousedown not working while input is focus

Tags: javascript

I have a little issue with the following code

The issue is: when my mouse is focused on the input (click into it, to write some text for example), the isKeyPressed function isn't called. Is it normal? And how could I fix it?

```js
function isKeyPressed(event) {
  if (event.ctrlKey) {
    console.log('CTRL + CLICK PRESSED');
  } else {
    console.log('NOT PRESSED');
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 img" onmousedown="isKeyPressed(event)">
  <div id="rectangle" class="rectangle-not-active"></div>
  <img class="file" id="my-image" alt="File" src="https://www.thalesgroup.com/sites/default/files/styles/article_card/public/database/d7/e-services_modified_1.jpg?itok=DkaYx8h8">
</div>

<input name="supplier" onfocusout="console.log('out')" onfocusin="console.log('in')" type="text" class="form-control" id="supplier" />
```

Comment: Please update the snippet I made to a [mcve]

Comment: The function `isKeyPressed` is called correctly beacuse the snippet error is: `Uncaught ReferenceError: removeZoom is not defined`

Answer (score 2):

Just remove redundant function call's which trigger an error.

And give `isKeyPressed` function to `img` tag `onmousedown` event

```js
function isKeyPressed(event) {
  if (event.ctrlKey) {
    zoom = true;
    console.log("we are in true bruh");
  } else {
    zoom = false;
    console.log("we are in false bruh");
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 img">
  <div id="rectangle" class="rectangle-not-active"></div>
  <img class="file" onmousedown="isKeyPressed(event)" id="my-image" alt="File" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='files/full/' + pdf['fullJpgFilename']) }}">
</div>

<input name="supplier"  type="text" class="form-control" id="supplier" />
```

Comment: But I want the isKeyPress fired on the `img` div, not the input :/

Comment: @NathanCheval I update my snippet.Check it out.RIght now it fire on the img div as you want.